# Texnicle on mac can't find file with pdflatex

Tags: errors, compiling, texnicle

I've been looking for couple hours now and I haven't found a solution for my problem yet. I am trying to build a PDF using Texnicle. I have set up pdflatex and its always giving me this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) restricted \write18 enabled.
Emergency stop.
<*> samplefile

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on texput.log.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `samplefile'.
<*> samplefile

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> samplefile

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on texput.log.
***------------------------------------------------------------
*** Running bibtex on samplefile ...
***------------------------------------------------------------
Compile aborted.
I couldn't open file name `samplefile.aux'
*** pdflatex.engine has completed.
```

Any ideas?

When I use console or Latexian, it's all fine!

So long...

Comment: Is your file called `samplefile.tex` ? and is the log file `texput.log` generated in the directory containing your file? If the answer to either of those is no then your editor is not trying to process the file that you want it to process.

Comment: Yes and yes log files is there...

Comment: Edit: samplefile.tex is there but in a directory that I created within texnicle... the log file is in the projectfile directory (one above)... Ive loaded the file directly and this is working...

Comment: ok, that simple it can be... I have to have the main file in the same directory as my projectfile... all good now! Thx for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact I've never heard of Texnicle it appears that it runs latex at the location of the project file, so your main tex file needs to be there (or on teh Tex input path) otherwise TeX won't find it.